# How to access individual strings within a split text file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, text, split

I need a way to access column values (delimited by \t) from a section of a text file.

The text file has sections separated by "*". I could find those sections using the simple below code.

```
 var text = File.ReadAllText("PIP_geometries.csv");

 var FlowlineSections = text.Split('*');
```

Within each section, there are 3 columns with headers and some rows of data. I want to get to these values.

For example:

```
*

Name  Country  
John  USA

Jack  Russia

Jim   USA

*

Name  Country

Ross  NZ

Moss  UK
```

In the code behind, the entire section after splitting looks like a single string. How do I get "USA" for "JIM"

Comment: You split string once, the answer is to split your strings again.

Comment: Who has created this text file format? You can kick him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so one way to do it would be

```
var secondsplitter = new [] {"\r\n","\n","\r"};
@"*

Name  Country  
John  USA

Jack  Russia

Jim   USA

*

Name  Country

Ross  NZ

Moss  UK"
    .Split('*')
    .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .Select(x => x.Split(secondsplitter,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

which gives

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

try this
var FlowlineSections = text.Split('*')[1].Split(vbTab);

Answer (score 0):

After your first split, your first string should be something like:

`Name\tCountry\nJohn\tUSA\nJack\tRussia\nJim\tUSA`

So you'll need to split it by `\n` to get each individual lines, and then for each line (skipping the first line if you don't care about the headers) you'll need to split it by `\t`. How you handle those results are up to you. You could turn it into a list of string lists, a dictionary, or populate some object type you create.